# Mostrar modal de forma automática con Javascript o Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, modal

Soy bastante principiante y estoy haciendo un sitio web con Bootstrap. Para el consentimiento de cookies, el cliente ya tiene un servicio que es PDO Cookie Consent y me envió toda la documentación para implementar los scripts en el sitio, lo hice y funciona a la perfección. Pero ahora quieren la posibilidad de que la ventana modal aparezca de forma automatica, luego de unos segundos, desde que el usuario ingresa a la web.
Ahi esta el problema, no sé como hacer para "llamar" a esa ventana. Según la documentación, se debe aplicar una clase al botón que quieras para que la ventana se muestre, pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo de forma automática, sin que el usuario haga click.
Probé con algunas cosas básicas que sé de Javascript, pero no logré nada. Después busqué con Jquery simular el click del usuario, probé de varias formas, pero no sé si lo estoy haciendo bien.
Este es el código que tengo y funciona

```
  <script charset="utf-8" src="https://pdcc.gdpr.es/pdcc.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    PDCookieConsent.config({
          "brand": {
              "dev" : true,
              "name": "Nombre de la empresa",
              "url" : "https://paginaweb.com",
              "websiteOwner" : ""
             },
            "cookiePolicyLink": "",
            "hideModalIn": [""],
        "styles": { 
            "primaryButton": { 
                "bgColor" : "#F7C03E", 
                "txtColor": "#036900"},
        "secondaryButton": { 
            "bgColor" : "#EEEEEE",
            "txtColor": "#333333"}
        }})
        
  </script>
```

Y aqui el botón que muestra esa clase

```
<button class="cokies"><a href="#" class="pdcc-open-modal">Politicas de Privacidad</a></button>
```

Probé con estos códigos y algunos más

```
//Primer intento
$(".cokies").trigger("click");
//otro intento
$("#pdcc-open-modal").trigger("click");

//otro intento
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.cokies').click(function(){
     setTimeout($('.pdcc-open-modal').fadeIn, 3000);
  });
});
```

Cuando el modal se abre desde el botón, con el inspector de elementos, se muestra como una pequeña web dentro del DOM con su body y head independiente ¿puede ser que la diferencia esté ahi? ¿Cómo llamo a una ventana externa, que "viene" desde una url?
Gracias!!!

Comment: No se entiende, dices que ya tienes el codigo hecho y funciona, entonces tu pregunta es si esta bien implementado?

Comment: Perdón... mi pregunta la hice medio larga y genera confusión. Lo que quiero es que esa ventana se abra de forma automática. Por ahora, sólo se abre haciendo click en el botón que dice "Politicas de privacidad" pero el cliente quiere que se abra sola una vez que carga la web.

Comment: Nos podrias decir que version usas de bootstrap y un ejemplo tal vez en [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/) o similar seria de ayuda, si te sirve y utilizando version 4 de bootstrap solo con $('.pdcc-open-modal').modal('show'); deberia funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Gracias amigos por todas las ideas!! Al fin lo pude resolver, imitando el click del usuario.
Mi error estaba en que dentro de button tenía una etiqueta  y así no funciona. Así que lo modifiqué así

```
 <button class="pdcc-open-modal" id="cokie">Politicas de Privacidad</button>
```

y en el script

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
      $(".pdcc-open-modal").click();
  },3000);

});
```

Así, cuando carga la página a los 3 segundos se abre el modal
Espero que pueda ser de utilidad en algún momento.